# python3-pip installed but pip3 command not found?

Tags: python, kubuntu, pip

I am testing a Python3 program in several computers. To do that, I need to install a library of Python with `pip3`.

So first, I was installing `python3-pip` in each computer (everyone is running Kubuntu OS). Everything was OK, and then I installed the package I needed with `pip3`, and I managed to do that except for one computer.

In that computer, `python3-pip` was apparently installed succesfully, but when I look for the package, I get this error (the translation is homemade):

```
Command «pip3» was not found, maybe you wanted to say:
 The command «pip» from the package «python-pip» (universe)
pip3: command not found
```

**EDIT**

Results of `dpkg -L python3-pip`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/pip-3.2.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3-pip/copyright
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/pip-3.2
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/log.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/unzip.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/zip.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/completion.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/help.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/bundle.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_pkgutil.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/status_codes.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/git.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/bazaar.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/baseparser.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/runner.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/backwardcompat.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info/not-zip-safe
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip-1.1.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
```

Comment: Could you maybe accept the answer, if it was helpful? This marks the question as resolved and will help future users.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

One of three things will likely fix it:

1. In case `python3-pip` did *not* install correctly, re-install it:

   This is used for Debian-based distros like Ubuntu, Mint:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove python3-pip; sudo apt-get install python3-pip
   ```

   If using Fedora, CentOS, RHEL, please use:

   ```
   sudo dnf reinstall python3-pip
   ```
2. Try using the command `python3-pip` instead (works on Fedora; I don't have a copy of Kubuntu to try it on).
3. Just a wild guess...check `pip --version`. There is a slight possibility that after installing `python3-pip` the new `pip` would *replace* the old `pip` (perhaps via `alternatives`?)

**EDIT**
Now that the output of `dpkg -L python3-pip` has been added to the question, I can provide the answer.

**The correct command name to use is: `pip-3.2`.**

Comment: It's not possible to reinstall python-pip3 (in Fedora at least), since dnf depends on it. In my case, I have python-pip3 installed, it should have installed /usr/bin/pip3, but didn't. `rpm -ql python3-pip|grep bin/pip3` shows `/usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip3.5`, but `ls /usr/bin|grep pip3` doesn't find them.

Comment: @dfarrell07 Wrong. You are not allowed to `dnf remove` it, since `dnf` depends on it. However, you are allowed to `dnf reinstall` it, which is what is needed anyways. `dnf` (and `yum` before it) is smart enough to know that reinstalling a needed package is OK even if removing it isn't.

Comment: That wasn't in your answer, but I updated it to make it clear.

Comment: should based on the python version, such as python 3.6, `pip-3.6`

Comment: @XinMeng Correct. I was pointing out that the command name from the `dpkg` output is `pip-3.2`. Obviously the `dpkg` output will be different for a different version of `pip`.

Comment: I had `python3-pip` installed and was able to use `pip3` to install the packages, I cant directly answer this question but hopefully this comment will help others

Comment: This is the right answer but not that helpful, because many utilities/scripts out there will attempt to execute "pip3", not "pip-3.6" etc.  You can't go and fix all those third-party scripts.  My suggestion, after installing python3-pip, check the binary path and then link it -- e.g. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip-3.6 /usr/bin/pip3`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem and found the solution. The `python3-pip` package installed a `pip-3.2` binary.

Executing `pip-3.2 --version` shows:

```
pip 1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.2)
```

Whereas `python3-pip` gives the `command not found` message.

I tested it on a "clean" download from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/

I checked for `pip-3.2` before installing `python3-pip` and then after.

Comment: pip-3.6 now, in my case - this worked. Thanks and +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have several Python versions installed, you might get:

```
bash: pip3: command not found...
Packages providing this file are:
'python36'
'python39-pip'
'python38-pip'
```

Listing the installed pips shows why:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep pip.*3

pip-3.6 -> ./pip3.6
pip3.6
pip-3.9 -> ./pip3.9
pip3.9
```

Resetting pip3 link could resolve it:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3.9 /usr/bin/pip3
$ pip3

Usage:   
  pip3 <command> [options]
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use use easy_install:

```
apt-get install python3-setuptools
easy_install3 pip
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this does and why it works?

Comment: This might be solution, but the question is oriented more to finding out what cause the error rather than finding the solution.