# Map pip3 command to run pip-3.2 on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy, python3.2

i installed GNUroot and the wheezy package from the app store on my android 4.4.2, after initially panicking when i couldnt run pip3, i discovered in this [python3-pip installed but pip3 command not found?](https://superuser.com/questions/769920/python3-pip-installed-but-pip3-command-not-found)
that the correct command to use is actually pip-3.2, is there a way to make the system understand that when i run pip3 it should invoke pip-3.2 as the command?

Comment: What you're looking for is this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task you an use an [alias](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).

```
alias pip3="pip-3.2"
```

This will do the job. To make the change permanent append this line to your `~/.bashrc` file.

You can use the `unalias` command to remove a previously set alias again. E.g.: `unalias pip3`